# Tomcat - is it possible to see all availables URIs?

Tags: tomcat

When I debug a sever deployed with Tomcat, it can be very useful to see the list of all the URIs published under the server. Is it possible?

Comment: I doubt you can get list of ALL available URLs, but maybe you could obtain something useful (like available context paths, host and port information) from Tomcat JMX MBeans http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/funcspecs/mbean-names.html